# Extract total number of rows based on categorical column based on a cut off column

Tags: pandas

I have following dataframe. I want to extract the total number of positive and negative rows (individually) when I give a set of cut off based on column 'score'.

```
cut_off = [1,2,3,4]

ID  SCORE  STATUS 
1   10.42  positive
2   9.22  positive
3   1.23  positive
4   7.84  positive
5   8.49  positive
6   6.86  positive
7   7.10  positive
8   0.45  negative
9   -7.19  negative
10   2.99  negative
11   3.53  negative
12  -1.88  negative
13  -2.57  negative
14   4.48  negative
15   2.02  negative
16   5.78  negative
```

For example:

cut_off=1
Positive: 7
Negative: 5

cut_off=2
Positive: 6
Negative: 5

and so on..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for co in cut_off:
    print((df['SCORE'] > co).sum())
```

The other one is apparently len(df.index) - n1.

Upd: if you can have the exact equality, then for the negatives it's the same:

```
(df['SCORE'] < co).sum()
```